# Identify ip address of the machines that accessing another machine in LAN

Tags: networking

What are the ways to detect the Ip-address of the machine that are accessing another machine/server/PC in a LAN?I'm trying to figure out who among of them are accessing the machine that I'm monitoring.Cos there's a lot of traffic happening on that machine, when I accces it takes time to load a the list of directory.

Comment: Need more info, eg accessing what service, how are you monitoring, directory list of what?

Comment: I'm monitoring file transfer and access.

Comment: What kind of file transfer? (There are lots!) Reason for asking, by the way, is that if it's a specific service that's being used, you may be able to get useful information from the management tool for that service. For example, if it's Windows file transfer (SMB) then you can run fsmgmt.msc and it will list who has active connections.

Comment: copying,pasting,downloading and deleting.

Comment: My bad, not being clear. I mean what protocol are they using? Is it Windows File Sharing? Web downloading? FTP? SCP? SFTP? Appletalk? NIS? WebDav? rcp? rsync? Bittorrent?

Comment: Whew, if I wasn't being clear before I doubt that alphabet soup helped. :-) So, another way to put it, what software do they use on their computer to access these files? Is it a web browser? Windows Explorer? Something scary on a command line? Also, what operating system is on both ends? Windows? OSX? Linux?

Answer (score 2):

The tool for this is called [netstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat), and is available on Windows and most Unixes.

Comment: By the way, netstat will work regardless of the protocol unless they're using something very weird: I'm asking about the protocol in my comments above because it may mean there's an easier way to get the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

The best tool for this is *wireshark* imho...  http://www.wireshark.org/

By using filters (Ip address, MAC address, Protocol...) you will be able to spot where the problem come from...

Hope this help. Let us know.